# Function in postgres with return many rows with some null value

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, stored-functions

i have little problem with function in postgress means. 
I have function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test(
    x integer,
    y character varying,
    z character varying
)
 RETURNS TABLE(x1 int, y1 varchar,n1 varchar,z1 varchar) AS
$BODY$
BEGIN
   RETURN QUERY
SELECT  x,y,null,z  FROM example_tab            
END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100
  ROWS 1000;
```

When I execute this function I take error:

```
 Error: Returned type unknown does not match expected type character varying in column 3.

 SELECT * FROM test(694531020,'t'::varchar,'t'::varchar)
```

What should I do to correct run this query and execute this function ???

Comment: `SELECT  x,y,null::varchar,z  FROM example_tab` and please remove mysql and sql-server from tags

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should explicitly specify datatype for null, like:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test(
    x integer,
    y character varying,
    z character varying
)
 RETURNS TABLE(x1 int, y1 varchar,n1 varchar,z1 varchar) AS
$BODY$
BEGIN
   RETURN QUERY
SELECT  x,y,null::varchar,z  FROM example_tab            
END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100
  ROWS 1000;
```

Comment: What is the logic in casting null (an unknown value) as an integer?

Comment: to match types of return table I suppose